# Add constraint to table from Rails - ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration, rails-activerecord

I have two associated models in Rails. User, and Post.

Whilst adding a boolean value column, 'Avatar' to the posts table, I would like to make a true value unique to the user to which it belongs.

In other words users can only have one 'Avatar' post with a value of true. This is because these posts (which are pictures) can be used as a users Avatar.

The posts already belong to users, and users have many posts, so I would like to set the constraint that users only have one post with a value of true for Avatar. Also if a new Avatar is uploaded/selected, then for this action to cancel out and falsify any previous Avatar.

This is my migration file so far:

**add_avatar_to_user_profiles.rb**

```
class AddAvatarToUserProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :posts, :avatar, :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20151018160617) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "comment"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "post_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "comments", ["post_id"], name: "index_comments_on_post_id", using: :btree
  add_index "comments", ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "caption"
    t.integer  "likes"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
  end

  add_index "posts", ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "sessions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "session_id", null: false
    t.text     "data"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "sessions", ["session_id"], name: "index_sessions_on_session_id", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "sessions", ["updated_at"], name: "index_sessions_on_updated_at", using: :btree

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["provider"], name: "index_users_on_provider", using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["uid"], name: "index_users_on_uid", using: :btree

  add_foreign_key "comments", "posts"
  add_foreign_key "comments", "users"
  add_foreign_key "posts", "users"
end
```

Hoping the above is enough to make sense, I have searched docs to no avail, am thinking the solution should be simple enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a custom validator in your `Post` model like this:

```
# post.rb
validate :unique_post_avatar

private

def unique_post_avatar
  if self.user.posts.select { |p| p.avatar == true }.count > 1
    errors.add(:avatar, "only one post avatar for this user can be true")
  end
end
```

which is essentially selecting the user's posts where the avatar is true. If this count is greater than one, then it will throw validation error. I think this is what you are looking for :-)